# Phonegap app Crashes at Runtime

Tags: android, cordova

When i Try to run my app from both simulator and phys device it crashes, heres the log

I have phonegap 1.3.0 :)

```
01-12 14:13:51.742: W/dalvikvm(344): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.philipslighting.roadlight/com.philipslighting.roadlight.PhilipsRoadlightFinalActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.philipslighting.roadlight.PhilipsRoadlightFinalActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.philipslighting.roadlight-1.apk]
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.philipslighting.roadlight.PhilipsRoadlightFinalActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.philipslighting.roadlight-1.apk]
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-12 14:13:51.791: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  ... 11 more
01-12 14:13:51.821: W/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.philipslighting.roadlight/.PhilipsRoadlightFinalActivity
01-12 14:13:52.341: W/ActivityManager(61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4053ec18 com.philipslighting.roadlight/.PhilipsRoadlightFinalActivity}
01-12 14:13:53.151: I/Process(328): Sending signal. PID: 328 SIG: 9
01-12 14:13:53.181: I/ActivityManager(61): Process com.roadlight.philips (pid 328) has died.
01-12 14:13:54.331: I/Process(344): Sending signal. PID: 344 SIG: 9
01-12 14:13:54.371: W/InputManagerService(61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405c2d80
01-12 14:13:54.621: I/ActivityManager(61): Process com.philipslighting.roadlight (pid 344) has died.
```

here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.philipslighting.roadlight"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

            <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:name=".activities.MainActivity" 
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>

            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Were in the activity tag would you you import the phone gap activity?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: hey buddy have you solved this problem,if so please tell me the solution as i am also suffering from this error.

Comment: I got the same problem after installing a new eclipse. Thanks to Alexender Volkov for the idea. It was happen because we need to re-link the cordova library again. Just add the jar file through "Configure Build Path" and tick the library inside "Order and Export" tab Thank alot.

Answer (score 9):

It you have used this tutorial http://phonegap.com/start#android
then to fix `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` as above you need to check the box next to cordova-XXX.jar in the "Order and Export" tab then you add a dependency for cordova-XXX.jar in Libraries tab at "Configure Build Path".

And of course mainclass's name must be correct at `android:name="<main class name>"`.

Comment: Worked for me too, any idea why I'm getting the error above at all (when the app worked before without a problem)?

Answer (score 5):

I was following the phonegap droid getting started guide
In my case, I had created a folder called `lib` instead of `libs`.  A symptom of this was that I had to manually add the jar to the build path.  I removed the jar from the build path, renamed the `lib` folder to `libs` and things started working immediately.

Answer (score 1):

In activity you import the file for PhoneGap please check it.
and see the index.html file in your folder.

I think just follow this path :
http://phonegap.com/start#android

See, video you will find solution for this.

Comment: I updated the Q, with the android manifest, could you please guide me to where in the manifest i have to import the Phonegap activity ?

Comment: If you are doing simple basic program with PhoneGap ..You just follow the steps as show into above link.
use  <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:name=".MainActivity">

Answer (score -1):

```
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

you should mention with package name along with main class name in 'activity' tag,look at below example:

android:name="com.philipslighting.roadlight.MainActivity"

```
       <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name="yourPACKAGEname.MainActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```